# How to fix some Xcode 13 bugs like not jumping to definition properly?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode13

I recently updated to Xcode 13 and suddenly the options from the "Show Code Actions" are not working anymore. That includes "Jump to Definition", "Show Quick Help", or even highlighting all the places where some propriety is being used.

Does anyone got the same problem or have some ideia to fix it? I already tried to close the app, to restart the computer, to clean the building folder, and nothing helped.

Comment: This is a Xcode 13.1 issue, I tried Xcode 13.2 beta and looks like this issue is gone.

Answer (score 6):

It is a currently known bug in Xcode 13.0. I just created a [sample project](https://github.com/andre-alves/xcode13-indexing-problem) and reported the bug to Apple – you could do the same to increase the odds of the fix getting prioritized.