# Xcode 13 doesn't show swiftinterface of the framework

Tags: swift, xcode13

I am trying

> Jump to Definition

of the **framework** swift interface, but **Xcode 13** does nothing.
Framework is made by previous Xcode versions.
Framework is attached correctly by Cocoapods and is working.
The only thing I can not navigate inside it swiftinteface.
The framework itself contains Modules section with the valid
***.swiftinteface**
files, but it is not indexed and not highlighted by Xcode.
Can somebody help with resolving this issue?

Comment: Known troubles with Xcode - clean/rebuild, relaunch, etc. Actually it is a bug - submit feedback to Apple.

Comment: I tried clean/rebuild, relaunch - does not help.

Comment: Did you try with Xcode 13.2.1? They fixed jump to definition in this version (from my tests)., but syntax highlighting is still not working. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69502129/how-to-fix-some-xcode-13-bugs-like-not-jumping-to-definition-properly/69560810#69560810

Comment: Yes, In Version 13.2.1 they fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Jump into definition was fixed in `Xcode Version 13.2.1`.
Just need to update Xcode.

That means that bug occurs only from Xcode 13.0 until 13.2.1.

Highlighting still do not work, but the way I see a solution is to
use third party apps for highlighting(For example: `Visual Studio Code`).